# Django: Is it possible to define a class related_name for all relational fields of a Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Does Django provide a way to define a generic related_name for all relational fields of a Model ?

Example :

```
class A(models.Model):
  pass

class B(models.Model):
  pass

class C(models.Model):
  pass

class D(models.Model):
  a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name="ds")
  b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name="ds")
  c = models.ForeignKey(C, related_name="ds")
```

Is there a way to specify only once the related name to use for fields a, b, c of model D, or do I have no other choice but typing it for each field ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: By default, related_name is <model_name>_set, I just want to know if there is a way to change this default value. Simple curiosity !

Comment: For example if you have a model Book that has a foreign key on a model Author and another on a model Editor, it is clearer to me to write author.books.all() and editor.books.all() rather than author.book_set.all() and editor.book_set.all() :)

Comment: Ah OK I understand better :) In that case, you can test the @Greg solution. Personally, I'd go with different names like `written_books` and `published_books`. it seems overkill but when the project get bigger, I like seeing in "which way" the objects are related

Comment: you can maybe consider implementing this as a meta options, in the same spirit of the ordering options, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, the feature is not present in Django up to 1.7, but is now available in the development version. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#default-related-name

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could do something like

```
class D(models.Model):
  name = "ds"
  a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name=name)
  b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name=name)
  c = models.ForeignKey(C, related_name=name)
```

But I'm not entirely sure I understand why you're wanting to avoid typing related_name="ds" a few times. Cheers!

Comment: You're right, it's not that hard to type this a few times ! It's just that I tend to think I'm doing something unclean when I write the same thing several times...